# How to handle xml response from the server?

Tags: php, ajax

I have a PHP script that sends xml to the browser in response to an ajax call.
Here's the code snippet:

```
$options=array($ok_option_1,$ok_option_2,$ok_option_3);
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>";
echo "<options>";
foreach($options as $value)
{
    echo "<option>";
    echo $value;
    echo "</option>";
}
echo "</options>";
?>
```

Here's the javascript that handles the response:

```
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
listOptions(xmlDoc);
function listOptions(xmlDoc)
{ 
    options=xmlDoc.documentElement;
    top_names=options.firstChild;
    top_names0=top_names.nodeValue;
    alert(top_names0);
    top_names1=top_names.nextSibling.nodeValue;
    alert(top_names1);
    top_names2=options.lastChild.nodeValue;
    alert(top_names2);
    return;
}
```

The alert boxes show that the variables `top_names0`, `top_names1` and `top_names2`
contain null. Please can you tell me where the problem is?

Comment: What does the actual response look like?

Comment: @Pekka:when i run the php file in the browser the response is

Comment: @Pekka:This page contains the following errors:

error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Comment: Yes, but what is the actual returned (xml) text?

Comment: @AkshayTakkar: if you aren't sure how to get the actual xml response I would suggest getting firebug (or it's equivalent for your browser). You can then see exactly what data goes where during ajax operations